# Suspected spam on remote support software question

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

2 user accounts have been created and all they have done collectively is **redundantly** suggest TeamViewer here, which is only a half valid answer given the full scope of the question:

[OS X: What remote support solution can be installed with the fewest clicks after a grandma is given a link?](https://superuser.com/questions/305097/os-x-what-remote-support-solution-can-be-installed-with-the-fewest-clicks-after/307109#307109)

I'm thinking this may be a deliberate SEO or spam attempt, what do you think?

What is meant to be done about this sort of stuff, if anything?

Comment: @studiohack, why remove the 'thanks'?  Does it increase your rep? Do you do that for a lot of questions? Bit of a trivial thing to take time to do? I want to thank the people for their attention.

Comment: thanks and signatures are not required here, and no, I don't get *anything* by doing it.  Cheers!

Comment: @studiohack If you don't get anything by doing it, why do it? Is saying thanks in questions banned? Thank you for this inquiry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that one of the two users had an IP address from one of the companies being recommended, and the other was from the same geographic area, I'm declaring this spam.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which company was the spammer affiliated with? I didn't think to do a WHOIS on their IPs, but I did notice that they were from the same geographical region, which seemed suspicious.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought that seemed like the sketchier of the two products. @DanielBeck's second thought was correct after all.

Comment: How do we retrospectively address their impact on all other areas of the site?

Comment: @LukeStanley their accounts were entirely removed, so there shouldn't be any remaining impacts. It was all nuked from orbit by @Dori.

Comment: Is it really likely that it's the only question they spammed?

Comment: A separate question, but are there any upcoming changes to consolidate repeat answer / solutions like this?

Comment: @Luke I guess we have several people (including mods) monitoring late answers to old questions (which are a gold mine for spam and cr.., erm, weak posts). Unfortunately, there's no automated way to prevent such things from happening.

Comment: Dori, the repetition I'm referring to is say, 5 different posts mentioning one product. As a programmer, consolidating these to one seems a logical move.

Comment: @Luke No need to consolidate, just remove. If it's already there, there's no additional value gained from a duplicate answer.

Comment: Unfortunately separating spam from genuine answers is very difficult, so consolidation to remote duplicates seems to me, to be the only long term technological solution, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Two unrelated companies, no referral codes... It's a worthless answer, but doesn't look like deliberate spamming. This looks more like a fan of these products dumping his unfiltered opinion into the site. Not being able to actually read would fit with that.

It's possible though that the user want to push the popularity of one of these products in a a non-obvious way. I know of team viewer, but have never heard of the other product.

Flag as low quality answer and have it removed. That's the easiest solution.

Comment: Yeah but would a spammer working for a company use a weak competitor to give the illusion of choice?

Comment: @Luke I suspected the other way. Mention your unknown product next to a very popular one, bound to receive upvotes. I know team viewer employees ough, so I miht not be impartial here.